# Mutating value on reference on const reference object

Tags: c++, constants

Why does this code compile (at least on MSVC and Clang)? I would expect that I can not change anything on a const object but it looks like contained, referenced object is non-const inside it?

```
class SomeObject {
public:
    int x;
};
class ContainerA {
public:
    SomeObject& s;
    int x;
public:
    ContainerA(SomeObject& s): s(s) {}
};
class ContainerB {
public:
    ContainerB(ContainerA const& a) {
        a.s.x = 1; // Const a but non-const a.s?
        //a.x = 1; // This fails as I expected...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to not compile? Maybe you can include that reasoning in the question.

Comment: Updated but comments in code should indicate what I’m getting at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no part of object `a` that gets modified when you say `a.s.x = 1`.

The object `a` holds a non-const reference `s` to an external object. The constness of `a` is unrelated to that of the object `s` refers to.

It is analogous to the situation of a pointer to non-const data member. The pointer itself cannot be mutated via a `const` reference, but the thing it points to can.

Comment: Does this not make const a little less useful? I mean, you can not prevent such mutation?

Comment: @UfoXp Not really, you just need to understand what references are. It would require pretty weird language rules to make this behave like you expect it to.

Comment: I do not know if slapping const on all member types is that weird? I always thought that this is how it works... So const is applied only on very right of member type? Thats how it is?

Comment: There is no part of `a` that is getting modified when you say `a.s.x = 1`. I will add it to the answer if it helps to clarify.

Comment: “constness of a is not related to s” - thats what is not completely clear to me. Why a member int constness is related but not member reference? Can I look at const on ContainerA const& as applying const to very right of member types of ContainerA? Yes, I know X& const is invalid syntax but you catch my drift?

Comment: @UfoXp No, the `const` applies to the object being referred to, and that includes its members. When you have `const& a`, that means you cannot call non-const members of `a`, and cannot perform non-const operations on data members of `a`. When you say `a.s.x = 1`, you are not mutating `s` (you can't, because references are immutable) but you are mutating the *object* it refers to. That object isn't a part of `a`. Since `s` has a non-const reference, it is OK to modify objects via `s`.

Comment: Erm, you say no but from your explanation it reads to me as yes... int is const because int const, SomeObject& is not const because SomeObject& const.

Comment: @UfoXp I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: I mean that when I write ContainerA const& I can read it as if ContainerA had members: { int const x; SomeObject& const s; } or in other words: { int x; SomeObject& s; } const => { int const x; SomeObject& const s; }